# Python classes and definitions

Tags: python

Here is my python code:

```
class Solution():
    def isPalindrome(self):
        return str(self.x) == str(self.x)[::-1]

s1 = Solution()
s1.x = 121
s1.isPalindrome()
```

It checks to see if the input is a palindrome. I want to create a new object that has the x value 121 and when I execute the isPalindrom function, I want it to return either a true or false boolean answer.

Currently when I run this program, nothing gets outputted. I am a bit lost as to where to go from here, would appreciate help.

Comment: you call the function, but you never ask for output. You could just do print(s1.isPalindrome()) to see the output displayed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just print out the return value of `isPalindrome()`, because if you have a line with only a return value (this case being a boolean), the compiler won't know what to do with it.

```
class Solution():
    def isPalindrome(self):
        return str(self.x) == str(self.x)[::-1]

s1 = Solution()
s1.x = 121
print(s1.isPalindrome())
```

Answer (score 1):

You're not telling the program to print anything. Try using print to make it reveal the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Along with printing results we can also make class more pythonic.

```
class Solution:
    def __init__(self):
        self.input = None

    def is_palindrome(self):
        if isinstance(self.input, str):
            return self.input == self.input[::-1]
        print("Error: Expects str input")
        return False  # or leave blank to return None


s1 = Solution()
print(s1.is_palindrome())
s1.input = "121"
print(s1.is_palindrome())
```

output

```
Error: Expects str input
False
True
```

Answer (score 0):

The main idea here is divide number. let's take number 122. First of all you need store it in a variable, in this case **r_num**. While loop is used and the last digit of the number is obtained by using the modulus operator **%**. The last digit **2** is then stored at the one’s place, second last at the ten’s place and so on. The last digit is then removed by truly dividing the number with 10, here we use **//**. And lastly the reverse of the number is then compared with the integer value stored in the temporary variable **tmp** if both are equal, the number is a palindrome,  otherwise it is not a palindrome.

```
def ispalindrom(x):
    r_num = 0
    tmp = x
    while tmp > 0:
        r_num = (r_num * 10) + tmp % 10
        tmp = tmp // 10
        if x == r_num:
            return True
    return False
```

Comment: Please provide an explanation as to why your answer is relevant. Plain code may be the answer but explanations enable us to learn.

Comment: I give some explanation. I hope it helps you to understand. Thank you for asking!